# Using EXCEPT in Calculated member

Tags: mdx, ssas

I have within an MDX query the following calculated member:

```
MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives (Inflation Linked)]
AS
(
    [Asset].[Class].&[Fixed Income],
    [Asset].[Sub Class].&[Derivatives],
    [Asset].[Sub Class Type].&[Inflation]
)
```

This is used within a query as follows:

```
SELECT
{
  [Measures].[Market Value]
} ON 0,
NON EMPTY(
{ 
    [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives (Inflation Linked)]
} ON 1
FROM [Asset]
```

This works fine, and of course gives me the market value of all Inflation linked Fixed income derivatives.

I now try to add a second calculated member, this time to give me all fixed income derviatives which are **NOT** inflation linked. I though this would be as easy as an `EXCEPT` in a second member like so:

```
MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives (Non Inflation Linked)]
AS
(
    [Asset].[Class].&[Fixed Income],
    [Asset].[Sub Class].&[Derivatives], 
    EXCEPT(
       [Asset].[Sub Class Type].[Sub Class Type], 
       [Asset].[Sub Class Type].&[Inflation]
    )
)
```

Alas, no luck - it yields the error

> The  function expects a string or numeric expression for the 
>   argument. A tuple set expression was
>   used.

Which is a confusing message, but par for the course in SSAS. Im sure im on the right track, and just have the EXCEPT slightly wrong, but I cant for the life of me spot the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use Aggregate function to achieve your goal without getting an error.

Change your calculated member definition as below;

```
MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives (Non Inflation Linked)]
AS
(
    Aggregate
    (
       {[Asset].[Class].&[Fixed Income]} * 
       {[Asset].[Sub Class].&[Derivatives]} * 
       EXCEPT
       (
        [Asset].[Sub Class Type].[Sub Class Type], 
        [Asset].[Sub Class Type].&[Inflation]
       )
       ,Measures.CurrentMember
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. Been bugging me for weeks.