# User defined hierarchy in an MDX query

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, mdx

Following on from [this question regarding calculating a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685403/using-except-in-calculated-member) I have 2 calculated members defined as:

```
MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives]
AS
AGGREGATE(
    {
       [Asset].[Class].&[Fixed Income],
       [Asset].[Sub Class].&[Derivatives]
    },
    [Measures].CurrentMember
)
MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Non-derivatives]
AS
AGGREGATE(
    {
      [Asset].[Class].&[Fixed Income],
      EXCEPT([Asset].[Sub Class].[Sub Class],[Asset].[Sub Class].&[Derivatives])
    },
    [Measures].CurrentMember
)
```

I can use these in an MDX query as follows:

```
SELECT
  {
   [Measures].[Market Value]
  } ON 0,
  NON EMPTY
  { 
   [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives],
   [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Non-derivatives]
   [Asset].[Class].[Class]
  } ON 1
  FROM [Asset]
```

And this gives me output as follows:

```
Class-----------------------|-MarketValue
============================|=============
Fixed Income Derivatives    | 12345
Fixed Income Non-derivatives| 54321
Fixed Income                | 66666
Property                    | 123
Equity                      | 987
```

Note that the first 2 rows are actually constituant parts of Row 3. Now, I can do some magic with the client code which reads this data to turn that table into a hierarchy, but - and here's the question - can I do it using MDX? Or am I just complicating things? Im not adverse to making changes in the cube if necessary, or if I could define this hierarchy there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just returning both Class and Sub Class, and building the hierarchy in client code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't use MDX to get a result that is supposed as hierarchy at the client side without some magic with the client code or changing the cube structure. Even though you can find a trick to fake the client the result as an hierarchy i don't suggest you to go that way.

Here is my suggestion.
**If i understand correctly**, you want to get a result that is kind of an unbalanced hierarchy tree that looks like below.

**[Asset].[Class]**

- [Fixed Income]

  - [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Derivatives]
  - [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income Non-Derivatives]
- Property
- Equity

This kind of unbalanced trees can only be implemented by parent-child hierarchies.

You can either try to balance the hierarchy by adding an intermediate level (or leaf levels) that includes `Property` and `Equity` members or create a parent-child hierarchy to achieve even deeper level unbalanced tree.

**Edit**

Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198072%28SQL.80%29.aspx) about parent-child dimensions.

Comment: One node has children (Fixed Income) and 3 nodes have none. Is that the definition of an Unbalanced tree?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an article link about parent-child dimensions and unbalanced hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding the calculated member this way:

```
WITH MEMBER [Asset].[Class].[Fixed Income].[Derivatives] AS ...
```

Comment: tried that one... Fixed Income is the bottom of the hierarchy as far as its concerned and wont let me add further children.